# How to slow down mouse speed when using win32api

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm attempting to make my mouse slowly go across my screen but have had trouble finding a way to slow down the mouse speed. Someone posted a solution to an issue 11 months ago the solution they posted isn't working for me or I am using it wrong.

Possible Solution: [How to change the mouse movement speed with win32api (mouseeventf_move)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74589285/how-to-change-the-mouse-movement-speed-with-win32api-mouseeventf-move)

```py
def farm():
    #win32api.SetCursorPos((0,1440))
    win32api.mou0se_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(100) * 2, int(100) * 2, 0, 0)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(1) * 5, int(3) * 7, 0, 0)
    #win32api.SetCursorPos((2560,1000))
```

So far I have attempted the code in the snippet above. The uncommented code is the attempted solution that I tried using from another post. This moves the mouse in the x and y direction of the first two numbers that are multiplied by a smoothing factor. I haven't found a way to slow down the speed with this method. If there is a way to do it while using SetCursorPos that would be great but if not I can understand why.

Edit: Removed the image and added a snippet, didn't know about not uploading images my bad.

Comment: Sorry about that, all fixed up. Thanks for letting me know! @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Answer (score 0):

I did quite a lot of digging, and unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to make win32api work.

I would recommend using **pyautogui** instead of win32api. Pyautogui is a GUI automation module, that can control the mouse and keyboard, as well as find images on screen and take screenshots using Pillow.

Pyautogui has the `moveTo()` and `move()` functions that should solve your problem. For example:

```
import pyautogui

def farm():
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration=2) #moves to (100, 100) in 2 secs
    #or if you just want to move the mouse, without specifying a position:
    pyautogui.move(None, 10, duration=2) #moves 10 pixels in 2 secs
```

Simply adjust the duration parameter to control the amount of time the mouse takes to move. I've been using pyautogui for a while now, and it has proven to be quite useful. I got this information from https://pypi.org/PyAutoGUI/, where you can find the link to the full documentation.

If pyautogui doesn't work for you, then I recommend checking out pynput, and there are plenty of stackoverflow posts about it (I'm not that experienced using pynput).